# Navbar fade and show at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently I am building a navigation bar using Bootstrap v4 and I found out that the animation during collapsing in responsive view is not right.

Hence, I inspect the specific navigation bar and I found out that the classes (.in and .show) are in the same elements when I toggle the collapsible content.

Is there any solution on it through JavaScript or by overriding CSS?

For your information, here are the inspection of my navigation bar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/34L2h.jpg

TQ.

---

**EDIT :**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark top-nav">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainmenu" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item px-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="#">SIGN IN</a>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="#">SIGN UP</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here are the jsfiddle link to the file.
https://jsfiddle.net/Jeffrey_Teoh/4y6n6xt4/11/

Comment: You need to at least include the relevant part of your code... ideally add a code snippet or jsFiddle

Comment: I had edited. Thanks for remind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are including bootstrap version 3 on top of your file and bootstrap version 4 at the end of your file... same with jQuery. Scripts should be added only once.

Comment: Noted that. I am really thanks to you. You save my day.